# Assembly x86 to y86 conversion

Tags: assembly, y86

I am trying to get an equivalent statement for a piece of y-86 code from x-86, but I'm a little skeptical and I just want to be sure. So with the following x-86 instruction, `addq 16(%rbp),%rax`.

I am translating the x-86 code of `addq 16(%rbp),%rax`, which says to calculate the value of `rbp + 16`, then add the value at the address just calculated and add it to `rax`, store in `rax`, correct?

My question is would the following y-86 do essentially the same thing?

```
rrmovq %rsp, %rbx
iaddq $0x16, %rbx
mrmovq (%rbx), %rax
```

Comment: Your description is correct, your code isn't. Hint: _"**add** it to rax"_

Comment: Ohh so instead of the last mrmovq it would be addq(%rbx), %rax, right?

Comment: If y86 allows that form, yes. Otherwise load it into `rbx` and add it separately.

Comment: Are you allowed to clobber extra registers for the y86 version?  x86 `addq 16(%rbp),%rax` doesn't modify any registers except RAX and FLAGS.  The address calculation for the addressing mode for the memory source operand is done internally, and so is the load.

Comment: Oops I just realized I was supposed to use rbp, but that's a good question, I don't think so, but how would you do it without overriding what's in %rax